# Snakemake: Generic input function for different file locations

Tags: snakemake

I have two locations where my huge data can be stored: `/data` and `/work`.

`/data` is the folder where (intermediate) results are moved to after quality control. It is mounted read-only for the standard user.
`/work` is the folder where new results are written to. Obviously, it is writable.

I do not want to copy or link data from `/data` to `/work`.

So I run my *snakemake* from within the `/work` folder and want my input function first to check, if the required file exists in `/data` (and return the absolute `/data` path) and if not return the relative path in the `/work` directory.

```
def in_func(wildcards):
    file_path = apply_wildcards('{id}/{visit}/{id}_{visit}-file_name_1.txt', wildcards)
    full_storage_path = os.path.join('/data', file_path)
    if os.path.isfile(full_storage_path):
        file_path = full_storage_path
    return {'myfile': file_path}

rule do_something:
    input:
        unpack(in_func),
        params = '{id}/{visit}/{id}_{visit}_params.txt',
```

This works fine but I would have to define separate input functions for every rule because the file names differ. Is is possible to write a **generic input function** that takes as input the file name e.g `{id}/{visit}/{id}_{visit}-file_name_1.txt` and the wildcards?

I also tried something like

```
def in_func(file_path):
    full_storage_path = os.path.join('/data', file_path)
    if os.path.isfile(full_storage_path):
        file_path = full_storage_path
    file_path

rule do_something:
    input:
        myfile = in_func('{id}/{visit}/{id}_{visit}-file_name_1.txt')
        params = '{id}/{visit}/{id}_{visit}_params.txt',
```

But then I do not have access to the wildcards in `in_func()`, do I?

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
def handle_storage(pattern):
    def handle_wildcards(wildcards):
        f = pattern.format(**wildcards)
        f_data = os.path.join("/data", f)
        if os.path.exists(f_data):
            return f_data
        return f

    return handle_wildcards


rule do_something:
    input:
        myfile = handle_storage('{id}/{visit}/{id}_{visit}-file_name_1.txt')
        params = '{id}/{visit}/{id}_{visit}_params.txt',
```

In other words, the function handle_storage returns a pointer to the handle_wildcards function that is tailored for the particular pattern. The latter is then automatically applied by Snakemake once the wildcard values are known. Inside that function, we first format the pattern and then check if it exists in `/data`.

Comment: This solved a problem for me as well since I wanted to pass the config dict to an input function in a separate file. Fantastic, thank you!