# Determining in Snakefile whether running in cluster mode or not

Tags: snakemake

Is there a generic way to tell whether snakemake was executed in cluster mode (e.g., --cluster, --cluster-sync, --drmaa)?

The use case is that in the cluster case I'd like to copy data from/to storage in some rules.

Answer (score 0):

No, this information is not intentionally exposed. A more snakemakeish way would be to keep such special handling out of the workflow definition. This way, the scalability of the workflow is not limited and the code is also not crowded with platform-specific stuff. Instead, you can use the `--default-remote-provider` argument if your storage protocol is supported, see [here](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/remote_files.html). Another possibility is to copy the files in the jobscript. Both strategies can be very flexibly implemented via configuration profiles, see [here](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/doc). A good example for a comprehensive profile that performs a similar task is [this one](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/surfsara-grid).

Comment: Thanks Johannes! Since this is mostly for local development while our cluster is busy with more important stuff, I'll simply make the copying conditional on the hostname for now. Your suggestions will come in handy for other purposes though!

Answer (score 0):

Would it help to use an input function to copy the files?

This solution helped me in a slightly related case:
[Snakemake: Generic input function for different file locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45728159/snakemake-generic-input-function-for-different-file-locations)